# Adding 52 new dates, each is a week from the previous, increments the dates with 30 years

Tags: android, date, calendar

I have this code that adds say 52 weeks to a date and creates 52 new dates (for reminders), but when I Log.d the dates that come out, I get the last date in year 2037. What am I doing wrong?

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Preferences.DATE_TIME_FORMAT_TWO);
    Calendar hoursAndMinutes = new GregorianCalendar(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar newDate = now;
    int weeks = reminder.getNumberOfWeeks();
    int reminders = reminder.getReminders().size();
    int currentWeekOfTheYear = newDate.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

    for (int week = 0; week < weeks; week++) {
        newDate.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, currentWeekOfTheYear + week);
        dateFormat.format(newDate.getTime());
                                for (int chosenDayIndex : chosenDaysOfTheWeek) {
            newDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, chosenDayIndex);
            dateFormat.format(newDate.getTime());
            for (int reminder = 0; reminder < reminders; reminder++) {
                try {
                    hoursAndMinutes.setTime(sdf.parse(reminder.getReminders().get(reminder)));
                    newDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hoursAndMinutes.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                    newDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, hoursAndMinutes.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                    newDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    newDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, +Utils.getRandomNumberBetween(1, 999));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                long dateInMiliseconds;

                dateFormat.format(newDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Can you please clearly define what you intend to do.

Comment: I am setting reminders for certain days, certain hours and a certain number of weeks in the future. But when the number of weeks is big, like 52 for example, years start incrementing rapidly

Comment: So you wish to add a reminder after X-Weeks, Y-Days and Z-Hours. Is it exactly what you want?

Comment: Yes. the problem is adding lots of weeks increments years rapidly

Comment: You have not even presented a short **compilable** code example so it is almost impossible to analyze your code (even closing brackets are missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is using newDate in a way too complex way.  If you want to add 1 week each iteration, use newDate.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);  That will increment it by exactly 1 week.  Then don't set any other field, that should be enough.

Comment: so instead of newDate.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, currentWeekOfTheYear + week); I should do newDate.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1); and change nothing else in my code?

Comment: Move all the other sets.  Do them once, rather than in the loop-  there's no reason to set the hour, day, minutes, etc multiple times.

Comment: Well, I also need to set certain week days and certain times for the reminders to go off, so I cant get rid of them